# tensorflow string_input_producer gives empty queue

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, image-recognition

I'm trying to make a queue in tensorflow from a list of file names. The list was made but it seems that the string input producer returned an empty queue. There might be other reasons that the code doesn't work. Below is the code:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)
    return images, key

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs, labels):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)
    image, key = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
    return image, key

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess, coord = coord, start=True)

input_pipeline(trainnames, batch_size, None, labels)

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide the error message, it would help.

In the same time, here are a few remarks on your code:

- The method `input_pipeline` defines the TensorFlow operators associated to your queue and add them to the graph so you should call it before calling `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`if you want the queue to be part of the graph and before the call to `start_queue_runners` if you want your queue to be started by the coordinator.
- You haven't asked TensorFlow to actually run your `image, key` operators.

Here is the code I would try:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)
    return images, key

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs, labels):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)
    image, key = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
    return image, key

# Let us define the queue operators and add them to the default graph.
image, key = input_pipeline(trainnames, batch_size, None, labels)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess, coord = coord, start=True)

# Let's run the image, key tensors.
sess.run([image, key])

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me how to combine the pipeline with the graph? I learnt that we cannot feed tensors to a placeholder of the graph, in this case how should I give input to the graph? I have a train set and a test set in two different queues, is it possible to input both of them to one graph? If I define a graph as a function, every time when I call it does it make a new graph or it returns the same old graph?

Comment: Well basically, the pipeline (e.g. `filename_queue`, `image`, `key`, ...) is part of the graph. If you don't want to feed placeholder tensors manually using a feed_dict, you can just use the image tensor to feed directly into the graph. Basically you just use your dequeue op as you would have used your placeholder.

I would recommend reading [the reading_data section](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) and have a look to the examples.

Regarding your last questions, this [section](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for helping me1 I have read that before opening the question, I'm still not sure what to do after reading it though. So I will add the filename_queue, image and key into the graph. I suppose running `sess.run([image, key])` will start dequeuing and going through the graph? Or is it just for obtaining the image tensors without training? For making pipeline part of the graph, I didn't find it how to give both pipelines of training set and testing set, do you know about this?

Comment: Yes it will run the dequeue operation and output the image. If you want to do something with the image in the graph, you should create new ops which use the image op: `train_op = use_image_to_train_model(image)` and call `sess.run(train_op)` or `test_op = use_image_to_test_model(image)` and call `sess.run(test_op)`